How to bind two functions to one event?
I want to have two different functions bound to the same event.
Some R code that doesn't work as I want:
library(tcltk)

callback1 = function(d) {
  cat('callback1',d,'\n')
  invisible()
}
tkbind('all','<<EVENT>>',callback1)

callback2 = function(d) {
  cat('callback2',d,'\n')
  invisible()
}
tkbind('all','<<EVENT>>',callback2)

w.top = tktoplevel()

invisible(tkevent.generate(w.top,'<<EVENT>>',data='ZZZZZ'))
invisible(tkevent.generate(w.top,'<<EVENT>>',data='1234567'))

The second call to tkbind overrides the effect of the first. This is correct behavior.
In tcl one does bind all <<EVENT>>  "+callback2 %d"
Python tkinter bind has an add="+" option.
Simply defining cb = function(d) { callback1(d) ; callbeack2(d) } , etc
would not be desireable. The reason is that callback1 and callback2
will almost certainly be in independent modules ("modules" used
loosely) and one doesn't want to couple them in this manner.
Trying things like tkbind('all','<<EVENT>>',+callback2) gives an immediate
error and it's totally obvious why. How do I get that "+" in there?

Would it be an option to create and bind a function callback_both(d) which calls both original callbacks?

As user @I_O suggested you can just use combined_callback to call both functions and then use tkbind('all','<<EVENT>>',combined_callback) to bind all events to this new function:
library(tcltk)
callback1 = function(d) {
  cat('callback1',d,'\n')
  invisible()
}
callback2 = function(d) {
  cat('callback2',d,'\n')
  invisible()
}

# Combine callbacks
combined_callback = function(d) {
  callback1(d)
  callback2(d)
}

tkbind('all','<<EVENT>>',combined_callback)

w.top = tktoplevel()
invisible(tkevent.generate(w.top,'<<EVENT>>',data='ZZZZZ'))

Output
callback1 ZZZZZ 
callback2 ZZZZZ 


You should give credit to @I_O, who suggested this in a comment.
